# Ember-Data "TypeError: this.container is undefined"

Tags: ember.js, controller, ember-data, containers, store

I'm trying to load the current user into the data store but am having some difficulty. The server uses PassportJS and visiting `/api/users/me` returns a JSON object similar to this:

```
{"user":{"_id":"53a4d9c4b18d19631d766980","email":"ashtonwar@gmail.com",
"last_name":"War","first_name":"Ashton","location":"Reading, England",
"birthday":"12/24/1993","gender":"male","fb_id":"615454635195582","__v":0}}
```

My store is just defined by `App.store = DS.Store.create();`

The controller to retrieve the current user is:

```
App.UsersCurrentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: null,
    retrieveCurrentUser: function() {
        var controller = this;
        Ember.$.getJSON('api/users/me', function(data) {
            App.store.createRecord('user', data.user);
            var currentUser = App.store.find(data.user._id);
            controller.set('content', currentUser);
        });
    }.call()
});
```

It is called by my application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "UsersCurrent",
    user: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.UsersCurrent")
});
```

I suspect the line `App.store.createRecord('user', data.user);` is causing issues but I don't have any idea how to fix it.

The console logs `TypeError: this.container is undefined` while the Ember debugger shows every promise is fulfilled and the users.current controller has no content. Thankyou for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you defining the store on the `App` namespace, because Ember Data doesn't do that by default.  Either way, you're failing to define the type you want to find after you create the record.

```
var currentUser = controller.store.find('user', data.user._id);
```

`createRecord` returns the record, so there is no point in finding it afterward

```
var currentUser = controller.store.createRecord('user', data.user);
```

Also in your example, you are trying to call the function immediately on the type, and not on the instance.  You should add that as a method to run on init.

```
App.UsersCurrentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    retrieveCurrentUser: function() {
      console.log('hello')
        var controller = this;
        Ember.$.getJSON('api/users/me', function(data) {
            var user = controller.store.createRecord('user', data.user);
            controller.set('model', user);
        });
    }.on('init')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/693/edit

Comment: Yes, I'm defining the store via `App.store = DS.Store.create();`. I added the type to find but this didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: That's not how the store should be defined.  Are you using an older version of Ember Data?  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: I'm using the current version. Are these docs out of date?
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by current version, since no versions been released, but yes, those docs are very much out of date. Let me create an example jsbin for you.  The transition documents are much more in date and correct.

Comment: Here's a simple one showing how you create adapters (no need to define the store, it's injected on all the controllers and routes) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/73/edit

Comment: I meant 1.0.0-beta8. Thankyou so much for looking at this, your solution works perfectly. I'll make sure to visit the transitional documentation more often.